# Presto - most current record before date

Tags: sql, presto

I have table `A`, containing `employee IDs` and sequential date steps since their employment `start date` (in this case `1x` employee who started on `1/1/1900`).

```
employee_id     date
1xxxxxxx      1/1/1900
1xxxxxxx      4/1/1900
1xxxxxxx      7/1/1900
1xxxxxxx      10/1/1900
1xxxxxxx      1/1/1901
1xxxxxxx      4/1/1901
1xxxxxxx      7/1/1901
1xxxxxxx      10/1/1901
```

I also have table B, containing all ratings an employee ever received:

```
employee_id  rating       date
1xxxxxxx       2        1/1/1900
1xxxxxxx       3        6/1/1900
1xxxxxxx       4        12/31/1900
1xxxxxxx       4        8/2/1901
1xxxxxxx       5        10/1/1901
```

How would I join `B` to `A` to obtain the most current rating for the employee as of date `A.date`?  This is the desired output:

```
employee_id   date      rating
1xxxxxxx    1/1/1900        2
1xxxxxxx    4/1/1900        2
1xxxxxxx    7/1/1900        3
1xxxxxxx    10/1/1900       3
1xxxxxxx    1/1/1901        4
1xxxxxxx    4/1/1901        4
1xxxxxxx    7/1/1901        4
1xxxxxxx    10/1/1901       5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to express this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.rating
        from b
        where b.employee_id = a.employee_id and
              b.date <= a.date
        order by b.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as rating
from a;
```

If you need more than one column, then a more complicated query is needed.  One approach is:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.*, b.*,  -- list the columns you want
             row_number() over (partition by a.employee_id, a.date order by b.date desc) as seqnum
      from a left join
           b
           on b.employee_id = a.employee_id and
              b.date <= a.date
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is good stuff thank you.  I do receive the following error when trying correlated subquery method (#1): `(GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR) line 13:9: Given correlated subquery is not supported`.  I guess the presto engine I'm working with won't support that approach :/

Comment: @NickBraunagel . . . I wasn't sure if Presto supported such correlated subqueries yet.  It should be able to transform it into a `JOIN`, but they must've decided that that work is not worth the effort.

Comment: Subquery decorrelation in Presto currently is able to to decorrelate a predicate when it's "near the top". It is not currently capable of decorrelating `ORDER BY` or `TopN` (`ORDER BY .. LIMIT`). This can be worked around by using `max_by` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) instead. I will post example as an answer, because it doesn't fit in here :) I created a ticket to track this -- https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1358

Comment: What if the `limit 1` subquery doesn't have matched row?

Answer (score 2):

(This is supplemental to @GordonLinoff answer)

Subquery decorrelation in Presto currently is able to to decorrelate a predicate when it's "near the top". It is not currently capable of decorrelating `ORDER BY` or `TopN` (`ORDER BY .. LIMIT`) ([issue](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1358)). This can be worked around by using [`max_by`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) instead. This turns a subquery into aggregation query which Presto can decorrelate.

```
WITH a AS ( SELECT 1 employee_id, 2 date ),
     b AS ( SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 3)) t(employee_id, date, rating) )

select a.*,
       (select min_by(b.rating, b.date)
        from b
        where b.employee_id = a.employee_id and
              b.date <= a.date
       ) as rating
from a;
```

```
 employee_id | date | rating
-------------+------+--------
           1 |    2 |      1
(1 row)
```